# C++ implementing abstract classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-base-class

I am trying to write a derived class called TerminalPlayer that inheritances a class Player given the declaration of virtual const Card playCard(const Card opponentCard) = 0; how would you implement the inherited playCard in the abstract class and what does the = 0 at the end of the prototype mean?

I also have the error in the main testing code that gives the error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Player’.  I think it is because I am not implementing the Player class correctly but I don't know how to fix it.

Player.h

```
    #ifndef PLAYER_H_
    #define PLAYER_H_

    #include <vector>
    #include "Card.h"

    #define MAX_HAND_SIZE 3

    // Abstract Player classS
    class Player {

        public:
            // Deconstructor
            virtual ~Player() {
            }

            // Play a card. If the player receives a joker then this player is going first
            virtual const Card playCard(const Card opponentCard) = 0;

            // Receive a card from the dealer
            void receiveCard(const Card c) {
                hand.push_back(c);
            }

            // Add points to the score
            void addScore(unsigned s) {
                score += s;
            }

            // Get the score
            int getScore() const {
                return score;
            }

            // Return true if the player has cards in the hand
            bool hasCards() const {
                return (hand.size() != 0);
            }

            // Receive the cards played from the previous round. This member function would be used by a computer player that may need to 'see' what cards were played.
            void cardsPlayed(const Card card1, const Card card2) {

            }

            // Output the players name
            friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Player& p);

        protected:
            // Constructor. Since this is an abstract class we do not want anyone instantiating a player class so we make it protected.
            Player(std::string name) :
                    score(0), name(name), hand(0) {
            }

            int score;
            std::string name;
            std::vector<Card> hand;
    };

    #endif
```

TerminalPlayer.h

```
    #ifndef TERMINALPLAYER_H_
    #define TERMINALPLAYER_H_

    #include "Player.h"

    class TerminalPlayer : public Player {
    public:
        TerminalPlayer(std::string name);
        virtual ~TerminalPlayer();
    };

    #endif
```

TerminalPlayer.cpp

```
    #include "Player.h"
    Card playCard(const Card opponnentCard){
        // TODO: playCard code here
    }
```

Test.cpp

```
    int main(){

        // This initialization give error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Player’
        TerminalPlayer player1 = Player("Player1");

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Paste the full error message in your question.

Comment: ERROR: Test.cpp:13:43: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Player’
ERROR: est.cpp:13:17: error: cannot declare variable ‘player1’ to be of abstract type ‘TerminalPlayer’

Eclipse is giving the error,
ERROR: The type 'TerminalPlayer' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'Player::playCard'
ERROR: The type 'Player' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'Player::playCard'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `= 0'` means that this is a `pure virtual` function.
This type of function must be defined by any class which inherits from the base class AND is instantiated within a program.

Since your base class declares:

```
// Play a card. If the player receives a joker then this player is going first
virtual const Card playCard(const Card opponentCard) = 0;
```

You should implement this function within your derived class.
You come close in TerminalPlayer.cpp:

```
const Card TerminalPlayer::playCard(const Card opponnentCard){
    // TODO: playCard code here
}
```

What you are missing the the `TerminalPlayer::` scoping shown above.
Also missing is the function declaration in the derived class. You need to add:

```
virtual const Card playCard(const Card opponentCard) override;
```

Within the class `TerminalPlayer`. Put it right after the destructor.

That should do it.

One thought: the const qualifier on the return value is not necessary since you are returning by value.

Comment: These little changes got those errors to go away but I still have to create a variable of type TerminalPlayer and call the Protected Player constructor base class.

I haven't been able to figure out how to declare a variable of type TerminalPlayer as listed in the OP in the Test.cpp section:

     TerminalPlayer player1 = Player("player1");

Comment: TerminalPlayer player1 = Player("player1"); Does exactly what you are saying you want to do. It instantiates TerminalPlayer as player1 and it should be calling the protected ctor.

Comment: I figured out what was going on.  The error given was incorrect but it ended up being that there wasn't a destructor (even if it was blank) in the derived class.  As soon as I added a blank destructor it compiled. BTW thanks for your orignal answer, that solved on of the biggest problems that I had.